# I use LD_PRELOAD to intercept open function

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I use LD_PRELOAD to intercept open function to read / proc / stat, read / TMP / proc file, I use vim and other commands are successful, but with w, uptime, top and other commands will read the information in / proc / stat.

Answer (score 1):

Some commands, including `uptime`, use `openat` instead:

```
$ strace uptime 2>&1 | grep '/proc/uptime'
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/uptime", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

Comment: What is this command for? I just want to change the load information of the CPU. Can you help me?

Comment: `openat` is just like `open`, but relative to an opened directory. Just intercept that as well.

Comment: 谢谢你  i am from china